# Verb/Subject Agreement Make/Makes

Tags: grammar, verb-agreement

I'm not sure about the proper subject verb agreement in the following sentences.

A boy and a girl make/makes a couple.

5 and 5 make/makes 10.

75 and 25 make/makes a hundred.

Can you help?

ETA: I understand that compound subjects usually take plural verbs, unless they form a collective idea- in which case it takes a singular verbs.

Can the subjects in these cases be considered a collective unit?

Comment: These questions are always interesting, since the compound subject is so arbitrary. This Wikipedia article is worth a read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_subject

Answer (score 1):

I think the right answer would be the following.

1. `A boy and a girl make a couple`, because ***they*** make.
2. `5 and 5 makes 10`, because I understand you're trying to convey sum, and that would be *5 plus 5*, or ***it*** makes.
3. `75 and 25 makes 10`, because I understand you're trying to convey sum, and that would be *75 plus 25*, or ***it*** makes.

Answer (score 0):

Answers 
 1] A boy and a girl make a couple.

2] 5 and 5 make 10.

75 and 25 make a hundred.
 Reasons: 1] 1 boy + 1 girl= 2.( More than 1)
2] 5 + 5 = 10.( More than 1)
3] 75 + 25 = 100 ( More than 1).
Hope you understand the logic.

Comment: Did you see my edits?