# Verb/Subject Agreement should it be make or makes?

Tags: subjects, verb-agreement

Mixing the ingredients and baking the dough make/makes a cookie. Neither one triggers the MS word spelling and grammar.

Also if someone could explain which answer to this is correct [Verb/Subject Agreement Make/Makes](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/308197/verb-subject-agreement-make-makes)

I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

This answer should shed some light: [Should I use the singular or plural verb in mathematical formulae ("Two and two make/makes four")?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9053/should-i-use-the-singular-or-plural-verb-in-mathematical-formulae-two-and-two)

Both are acceptable, but in my experience, in spoken American English, "makes" is more idiomatic. The feeling is that "mixing the ingredients and baking the dough" is *one* procedure. That is, the "mixing" and "baking" do not exercise joint agency to do the making. Even though syntactically, a plural noun phrase "x and y" is the subject, they comprise a single two-step procedure, which, if executed as a whole, makes the cookie.

I think this may be different in the UK, but I'm not sure.